# How to create and use a two dimensional array of classes

Tags: java, android

I was just experimenting with a two dimensional array of classes in java. I wrote the following (wrong) code:

```
public class GameEvent
{
    static int LAUNCH_ALIEN = 0;
    static int END = 1;

    long time;
    long cum_time;
    int alien_type;
    int event_code;
}
```

then

```
GameEvent[][] event_array = new GameEvent[MAX_LEVELS][MAX_EVENTS];
```

and accessed it with code like below (read comment in code):

```
event_array[lev][ctr].event_code = code; // nullpointer exception at runtime
```

So my question now is, what is the least painful way to change my code so that it works.

Comment: how does it not work?

Comment: Just initialize the array and it will work.

Comment: because that position is pointing to null :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GameEvent[][] event_array = new GameEvent[MAX_LEVELS][MAX_EVENTS];
```

This allocates the array of references to `GameEvent` objects but not the objects themselves.

To actually allocate the obects it is necessary to do it for every cell of the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEVELS; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < MAX_EVENTS; ++j)
    event_array[i][j] = new GameEvent();
```